# Getting "Called doStart when already started" from LoaderManager. Why?

Tags: android, android-loadermanager

My code has an Activity, that has a FragmentPagerAdapter that creates 'n' fragments as necessary.
Activity has a loader, and each fragment has its own loader. All loaders have unique ID.
(Activity's loader in fact determines the number of Pages in the adapter)

I keep getting this warning here and there and can't put my finger on what's causing it.
It doesn't seem to be critical, also looking at the LoaderManger's code throwing this warning, but still - warnings are usually signs for bugs..

Had originally used FragmentStatePagerAdapter and then moved to FragmentPagerAdapter, thinking that could somehow be the issue - but obviously it's not.

Posting code would really complicate this and add very little.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

in your fragment move your initLoader method inside the onActivityCreated method.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    LoaderManager lm = getLoaderManager();
    lm.initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm, and seems like a no-brainer now that I have your answer staring at me :-)   Thank you.

Comment: you are welcome, and if you switched to FragmentPagerAdapter because this problem, it should works too with the FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Comment: This did not help in my case, I still keep getting this exception when I attach / deattach to a fragment that inits a loader on onActivityCreated a couple times.

Comment: What is most imperative in answer is that `getLoader` must be called in `onActivityCreated`, if you call it before then, I was still seeing  issues even tho I called `init` in `onActivityCreated`

Comment: as explained by Google's Android class on Udacity: "Loaders are initialized in onActivityCreated because their lifecycle is actually bound to the Activity, *not* the Fragment", which explains why @mina 's answer is correct.

Answer (score 4):

I've just finished a few hours long debugging session with the support library.

TL;DR: **DO NOT CALL `getLoaderManager` in `Fragment.onCreate`, use [`onActivityCreated`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xxv/android-lifecycle/master/complete_android_fragment_lifecycle.png)!**
(this implies that you can't do `initLoader` before `onActivityCreated`)

`Fragment.getLoaderManager()` will lazily get a `LoaderManager` instance for you from the activity. However for this to be a valid one the fragment already has to be activated (`FragmentManager.makeActive`), which implies two things relevant here:

- the Fragment has been added
  (`FragmentManager.addFragment`)
- the Fragment has an internal identifier (`mWho`)
  (`makeActive` calls `Fragment.setIndex`)

The latter is really important because when you call `Fragment.getLoaderManager()` which in turn asks `FragmentActivity.getLoaderManager(who, ...)` for a real manager. When called from `Fragment.onCreate()` the `makeActive` call didn't happen yet so you'll get back a `LoaderManagerImpl` with `mWho == null` which is bad, because the framework will reassign the `LoaderManager` instance to every fragment which has similar lifecycle.

Because of this reassignment the `LoaderManager` has already been started by one fragment, but another one will try to start it as well, because the activity didn't know which fragment is asking, neither of them had their identity (`mWho`) yet.