# onCreateLoader not called when orientation changes

Tags: android

My problem is basically the same as this one:[Sometimes don't get onCreateLoader callback after calling initLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810019/sometimes-dont-get-oncreateloader-callback-after-calling-initloader)

I have 2 `ListFragments` that are contained in a `ViewPager`. They get loaded ok at first, but when I change the orientation, the `initLoader`method doesn't call the `onCreateLoader`.
However, if I revert back to the initial orientation, all is fine again.

Here is my code for the `FragmentActivity`:

```
import java.util.Locale;

import com.d.camera.R;
import com.d.camera.R.id;
import com.d.camera.R.layout;
import com.d.camera.R.menu;
import com.d.camera.R.string;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HistoryFragments extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
 * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
 * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_history_fragments);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager
            .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
        // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
        // this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                .setTabListener(this));
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.history, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.

        Fragment fragment = null;

        if (position == 0) {
            fragment = new HistoryListFragment();               
        } else{
            fragment = new HistoryElemListFragment();

        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 2 total pages.
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}


}
```

and here is the code of one of the `ListFragments`:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import com.d.camera.HistoryContentProvider;
import com.d.camera.HistoryDatabase;
import com.d.camera.HistoryEntry;
import com.d.camera.R;

import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FilterQueryProvider;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder;

public class HistoryListFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

    private static final int LOADER_ID = 0x01;
    private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;
    public static final String SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    private Context context;

    public HistoryListFragment() {
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        context = getActivity();
        fillData();
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }




    private void fillData() {
        getActivity().getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
        String[] from = new String[] {
                HistoryDatabase.MOBILE_RESULT,
                HistoryDatabase.FP_TIMESTAMP,
                HistoryDatabase.PRODUCT_IMAGE,};

        int[] to = new int[] {
                R.id.resultImage,
                R.id.time,
                R.id.productImage,};

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, R.layout.history_element, null, from, to, 0);


        // We want monitor the list setup and change the milliseconds time to a readable format.*******
        adapter.setViewBinder(new ViewBinder(){
            public boolean setViewValue(View v, Cursor c, int columnIndex) {

                if(columnIndex == c.getColumnIndex(HistoryDatabase.FP_TIMESTAMP))
                {
                    Long timeInMilli = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(HistoryDatabase.FP_TIMESTAMP));
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
                    String formatedTime = sdf.format(new Date(timeInMilli));
                    TextView tv = (TextView)v;
                    tv.setText(formatedTime);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        //*********************************************************************************************

        setListAdapter(adapter);

  }


    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        //...
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }



    // Reaction to the menu selection
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        //...
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        String[] projection = new String[]{HistoryDatabase.ID, HistoryDatabase.MOBILE_RESULT, HistoryDatabase.MOBILE_SCORE, HistoryDatabase.FP_TIMESTAMP, HistoryDatabase.PRODUCT_IMAGE, HistoryDatabase.QR_MESSAGE};
        return new CursorLoader(context, HistoryContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, HistoryDatabase.ID + " DESC");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
        adapter.swapCursor(cursor);     
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {
        adapter.swapCursor(null);           
    }   

    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

I've tried different combinations of these methods `destroyLoader`,`restartLoader`, but without any success... Does anyone know what's going on?

**Edit**
Using `LoaderManager.enableDebugLogging(true)` I get the following logs:
The first load gives this

```
 initLoader in LoaderManager{424a7950 in HistoryFragments{42507c68}}: args=null
   Starting: LoaderInfo{424a7da0 #1 : CursorLoader{42faae18}}
   Created new loader LoaderInfo{424a7da0 #1 : CursorLoader{42faae18}}
 initLoader in LoaderManager{424a7950 in HistoryFragments{42507c68}}: args=null
   Starting: LoaderInfo{42e5a280 #2 : CursorLoader{42e5a2f8}}
   Created new loader LoaderInfo{42e5a280 #2 : CursorLoader{42e5a2f8}}
 onLoadComplete: LoaderInfo{424a7da0 #1 : CursorLoader{42faae18}}
   onLoadFinished in CursorLoader{42faae18 id=1}: CursorWrapperInner{42506d58}
 onLoadComplete: LoaderInfo{42e5a280 #2 : CursorLoader{42e5a2f8}}
   onLoadFinished in CursorLoader{42e5a2f8 id=2}: CursorWrapperInner{42fab1f0}
```

Then when I change the orientation, it gives this

```
Retaining in LoaderManager{424a7950 in HistoryFragments{42507c68}}
   Retaining: LoaderInfo{42e5a280 #2 : CursorLoader{42e5a2f8}}
   Retaining: LoaderInfo{424a7da0 #1 : CursorLoader{42faae18}}
 Destroying Inactive in LoaderManager{424a7950 in HistoryFragments{42507c68}}
 initLoader in LoaderManager{424a7950 in HistoryFragments{426d0af0}}: args=null
   Re-using existing loader LoaderInfo{424a7da0 #1 : CursorLoader{42faae18}}
 initLoader in LoaderManager{424a7950 in HistoryFragments{426d0af0}}: args=null
   Re-using existing loader LoaderInfo{42e5a280 #2 : CursorLoader{42e5a2f8}}
 Finished Retaining in LoaderManager{424a7950 in HistoryFragments{426d0af0}}
   Finished Retaining: LoaderInfo{42e5a280 #2 : CursorLoader{42e5a2f8}}
   Stopping: LoaderInfo{42e5a280 #2 : CursorLoader{42e5a2f8}}
   Finished Retaining: LoaderInfo{424a7da0 #1 : CursorLoader{42faae18}}
   Stopping: LoaderInfo{424a7da0 #1 : CursorLoader{42faae18}}
```

Then when I come back to the initial orientation, I get an error but then everything gets loaded again:

```
Retaining in LoaderManager{424a7950 in HistoryFragments{426d0af0}}
 Called doRetain when not started: LoaderManager{424a7950 in HistoryFragments{426d0af0}}
 java.lang.RuntimeException: here
    at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl.doRetain(LoaderManager.java:795)
    at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:5497)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3591)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3654)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3854)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:159)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1322)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Destroying Active in LoaderManager{424a7950 in HistoryFragments{426d0af0}}
   Destroying: LoaderInfo{42e5a280 #2 : CursorLoader{42e5a2f8}}
   Reseting: LoaderInfo{42e5a280 #2 : CursorLoader{42e5a2f8}}
   Destroying: LoaderInfo{424a7da0 #1 : CursorLoader{42faae18}}
   Reseting: LoaderInfo{424a7da0 #1 : CursorLoader{42faae18}}
 Destroying Inactive in LoaderManager{424a7950 in HistoryFragments{426d0af0}}
 Destroying Active in LoaderManager{424a7950 in HistoryFragments{426d0af0}}
 Destroying Inactive in LoaderManager{424a7950 in HistoryFragments{426d0af0}}
 initLoader in LoaderManager{4271b070 in HistoryFragments{42702c68}}: args=null
   Starting: LoaderInfo{4271b690 #1 : CursorLoader{4271b708}}
   Created new loader LoaderInfo{4271b690 #1 : CursorLoader{4271b708}}
 initLoader in LoaderManager{4271b070 in HistoryFragments{42702c68}}: args=null
   Starting: LoaderInfo{42720ab8 #2 : CursorLoader{42720b30}}
   Created new loader LoaderInfo{42720ab8 #2 : CursorLoader{42720b30}}
 onLoadComplete: LoaderInfo{4271b690 #1 : CursorLoader{4271b708}}
   onLoadFinished in CursorLoader{4271b708 id=1}: CursorWrapperInner{4271f518}
 onLoadComplete: LoaderInfo{42720ab8 #2 : CursorLoader{42720b30}}
   onLoadFinished in CursorLoader{42720b30 id=2}: CursorWrapperInner{427222c0}
```

The logs then repeat themselves for further orientation changes. Why are the `CursorLoaders` being stopped and not restarted? How can I restart them?

**EDIT 2**

I fixed my problem thanks to nikis, but he raised an interesting question:
why was the `android.app.LoaderManager` not working?

Here's the logs after using the support version.
The first load gives the same thing as above, but after the orientation change, re-using the cursors doesn't stop them.

```
 Retaining in LoaderManager{43945c70 in HistoryFragments{427cb468}}
   Retaining: LoaderInfo{439d8a58 #2 : CursorLoader{439d8ad0}}
   Retaining: LoaderInfo{432dea88 #1 : CursorLoader{4393ad48}}
 Destroying Inactive in LoaderManager{43945c70 in HistoryFragments{427cb468}}
 initLoader in LoaderManager{43945c70 in HistoryFragments{438f0a38}}: args=null
   Re-using existing loader LoaderInfo{432dea88 #1 : CursorLoader{4393ad48}}
 initLoader in LoaderManager{43945c70 in HistoryFragments{438f0a38}}: args=null
   Re-using existing loader LoaderInfo{439d8a58 #2 : CursorLoader{439d8ad0}}
 Starting in LoaderManager{43945c70 in HistoryFragments{438f0a38}}
 Finished Retaining in LoaderManager{43945c70 in HistoryFragments{438f0a38}}
   Finished Retaining: LoaderInfo{439d8a58 #2 : CursorLoader{439d8ad0}}
   onLoadFinished in CursorLoader{439d8ad0 id=2}: CursorWrapperInner{43952be0}
   Finished Retaining: LoaderInfo{432dea88 #1 : CursorLoader{4393ad48}}
   onLoadFinished in CursorLoader{4393ad48 id=1}: CursorWrapperInner{43952fa8}
```

And when I come back to the initial orientation, this is the result:

```
Retaining in LoaderManager{43945c70 in HistoryFragments{438f0a38}}
   Retaining: LoaderInfo{439d8a58 #2 : CursorLoader{439d8ad0}}
   Retaining: LoaderInfo{432dea88 #1 : CursorLoader{4393ad48}}
 Destroying Inactive in LoaderManager{43945c70 in HistoryFragments{438f0a38}}
 initLoader in LoaderManager{43945c70 in HistoryFragments{432cab50}}: args=null
   Re-using existing loader LoaderInfo{432dea88 #1 : CursorLoader{4393ad48}}
 initLoader in LoaderManager{43945c70 in HistoryFragments{432cab50}}: args=null
   Re-using existing loader LoaderInfo{439d8a58 #2 : CursorLoader{439d8ad0}}
 Starting in LoaderManager{43945c70 in HistoryFragments{432cab50}}
 Finished Retaining in LoaderManager{43945c70 in HistoryFragments{432cab50}}
   Finished Retaining: LoaderInfo{439d8a58 #2 : CursorLoader{439d8ad0}}
   onLoadFinished in CursorLoader{439d8ad0 id=2}: CursorWrapperInner{43952be0}
   Finished Retaining: LoaderInfo{432dea88 #1 : CursorLoader{4393ad48}}
   onLoadFinished in CursorLoader{4393ad48 id=1}: CursorWrapperInner{43952fa8}
```

Comment: The answer here solved it in my case:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559573/getting-called-dostart-when-already-started-from-loadermanager-why

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `LoaderManager.enableDebugLogging(true)` to debug your loader behavior or you can try to use `getSupportLoadermanager()` instead of `getLoaderManager()`

Comment: Moving the fillData() method didn't work, it generated a `nullPointerException ` in the `onCreateLoader` method

Comment: Thanks for the `LoaderManager.enableDebugLogging(true)` trick, I've used it and updated my question.

Comment: Hm, please try android.support.v4.* version of the Loader API instead of android.app.LoaderManager. Does it help?

Comment: Thanks nikis, you put me on the right track! I was using `getLoaderManager()` instead of `getSupportLoaderManager()`! You made my day!

Comment: However, the root issue is not clear, I suppose standard `LoaderManager` is buggy in comparison with support one.

Comment: Yep, you're right! I added the logs I got when using the support version. The problem comes from the re-loading of the `CursorLoader`.

Comment: FYI the documentation for FragmentActivity states: "When using this class as opposed to new platform's built-in fragment and loader support, you must use the getSupportFragmentManager() and getSupportLoaderManager() methods respectively to access those features."

Answer (score 4):

It appears that this problem occurs when you combine some of activities from support libraries with android.app.LoaderManager.

I had exactly the same issue with android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity and android.app.LoaderManager:

- initial loading works
- then when orientation changes loader newer finishes
- and then when getting back to original orientation it works again.

By using android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager instead, everything started working perfectly again!

Comment: Strange but yes this is exactly what I observed too.

Comment: I used an AppCompatActivity with getLoaderManager and it kept losing the loader on rotate, as soon as I changed to getSupportLoaderManager it worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue as the OP in that `onCreateLoader` was not being called after a configuration change. However, that wasn't really the problem (as using `getSupportLoaderManager().enableDebugLogging(true);` showed that my loaders were being successfully re-used, so there was no need to recreate new ones).

So I looked into my `onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor)` method and found, unlike `onCreateLoader`, it was always called after a configuration change. And the `cursor` was being populated each time. :-)

The problem was that the position of the cursor was at the *end* of the resultset, so my attempts to iterate through it resulted in no action (and, consequentially, my UI not being populated).

The solution that worked was to move the cursor position to back before first:

```
// Move cursor before first so we can still iterate after config change
cursor.moveToPosition(-1);
```

I put that at the start of my `onLoadFinished` method.

Comment: I had the same issue. Doe this mean that after an orientation change, the same Cursor instance is passed to `onLoadFinished`? It's the only reason I can see for the position being at the end.

Comment: I would expect so. It might be worth doing a test to check: save the original cursor to a static variable (if the static variable is null) and then comparing it to the 'new' cursor.

Comment: This makes more sense to me now. I reread [Understanding LoaderManager](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/understanding-loadermanager.html) which explains that LoaderManager retains state across orientation changes so the data does not need to be queried again.

Comment: Thank you this saved my time

But I used cursor.moveToFirst();

Answer (score 1):

There was a work around documented on the question you referenced. Call restartLoader in onResume rather than create loader elsewhere. restartLoader will create if necessary.

Comment: I've already tried this when I first looked at the question. It doesn't work the problem persists.