# Using DrawerLayout forces using support library for LoaderManager?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-loadermanager

My app has some activities, no fragments, a DrawerLayout and all activities are using Loaders to get access to a database via a ContentProvider.  The problem I got in two of my activities (and not in the others) is similar to the one described in [onCreateLoader not called when orientation changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709446/oncreateloader-not-called-when-orientation-changes): 
when changing the orientation of the device getLoaderManager().initLoader() within onResume() is called but this leads to a callback of onLoadFinished() only in one of the two orientations (the initial one).  Repeated changes of the orientation always have the same effect.

The difference to the problem in [onCreateLoader not called when orientation changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709446/oncreateloader-not-called-when-orientation-changes) is that I am not using Fragments with FragmentActivity from the support library. But I have also to use the support library for the DrawerLayout.

Does using any part of the support library always enforce using the LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks also from the support library?
If yes, where do I find this information?

Using LoaderManager.enableDebugLogging(true) I get the following logs:
The first load of the activity:

```
initLoader in LoaderManager{4221a5a0 in RepairInfo{422051c0}}: args=null
  Starting: LoaderInfo{4221aab8 #12 : CursorLoader{4221abc0}}
  Created new loader LoaderInfo{4221aab8 #12 : CursorLoader{4221abc0}}
restartLoader in LoaderManager{4221a5a0 in RepairInfo{422051c0}}: args=Bundle[{PartTypeDbId=1, BikeDbId=23}]
  Starting: LoaderInfo{4221c128 #11 : CursorLoader{4221cee8}}
onLoadComplete: LoaderInfo{4221aab8 #12 : CursorLoader{4221abc0}}
  onLoadFinished in CursorLoader{4221abc0 id=12}: CursorWrapperInner{42224a58}
onLoadComplete: LoaderInfo{4221c128 #11 : CursorLoader{4221cee8}}
  onLoadFinished in CursorLoader{4221cee8 id=11}: CursorWrapperInner{42224b50}
Stopping in LoaderManager{4219c730 in BikeDescription{41e4f930}}
  Stopping: LoaderInfo{4219cfc0 #3 : CursorLoader{4219dc90}}
  Stopping: LoaderInfo{421a1b88 #2 : CursorLoader{421a2b50}}
```

Changing the orientation of the device I get this log - without any onLoadComplete and therefore without displaying the database data:

```
Retaining in LoaderManager{4221a5a0 in RepairInfo{422051c0}}
      Retaining: LoaderInfo{4221aab8 #12 : CursorLoader{4221abc0}}
      Retaining: LoaderInfo{4221c128 #11 : CursorLoader{4221cee8}}
    Destroying Inactive in LoaderManager{4221a5a0 in RepairInfo{422051c0}}
    Finished Retaining in LoaderManager{4221a5a0 in RepairInfo{4223a8d8}}
      Finished Retaining: LoaderInfo{4221aab8 #12 : CursorLoader{4221abc0}}
      Stopping: LoaderInfo{4221aab8 #12 : CursorLoader{4221abc0}}
      Finished Retaining: LoaderInfo{4221c128 #11 : CursorLoader{4221cee8}}
      Stopping: LoaderInfo{4221c128 #11 : CursorLoader{4221cee8}}
    initLoader in LoaderManager{4221a5a0 in RepairInfo{4223a8d8}}: args=null
      Re-using existing loader LoaderInfo{4221aab8 #12 : CursorLoader{4221abc0}}
    restartLoader in LoaderManager{4221a5a0 in RepairInfo{4223a8d8}}: args=Bundle[{PartTypeDbId=1, BikeDbId=23}]
      Making last loader inactive: LoaderInfo{4221c128 #11 : CursorLoader{4221cee8}}
    restartLoader in LoaderManager{4221a5a0 in RepairInfo{4223a8d8}}: args=Bundle[{PartTypeDbId=1, BikeDbId=23}]
      Current loader is stopped; replacing
      Destroying: LoaderInfo{4224ffe8 #11 : CursorLoader{422501e0}}
```

Changing the orientation of the device back to its initial orientation produces a warning, but has onLoadComplete and displays all data like the first call:

```
Retaining in LoaderManager{4221a5a0 in RepairInfo{4223a8d8}}
Called doRetain when not started: LoaderManager{4221a5a0 in RepairInfo{4223a8d8}}
java.lang.RuntimeException: here
    at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl.doRetain(LoaderManager.java:795)
    at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:5359)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3480)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3539)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3739)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1211)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Destroying Active in LoaderManager{4221a5a0 in RepairInfo{4223a8d8}}
  Destroying: LoaderInfo{4221aab8 #12 : CursorLoader{4221abc0}}
  Reseting: LoaderInfo{4221aab8 #12 : CursorLoader{4221abc0}}
  Destroying: LoaderInfo{42262f28 #11 : CursorLoader{42263120}}
Destroying Inactive in LoaderManager{4221a5a0 in RepairInfo{4223a8d8}}
  Destroying: LoaderInfo{4221c128 #11 : CursorLoader{4221cee8}}
Destroying Active in LoaderManager{4221a5a0 in RepairInfo{4223a8d8}}
Destroying Inactive in LoaderManager{4221a5a0 in RepairInfo{4223a8d8}}
initLoader in LoaderManager{42280020 in RepairInfo{4226cf08}}: args=null
  Starting: LoaderInfo{42280538 #12 : CursorLoader{42280580}}
  Created new loader LoaderInfo{42280538 #12 : CursorLoader{42280580}}
restartLoader in LoaderManager{42280020 in RepairInfo{4226cf08}}: args=Bundle[{PartTypeDbId=1, BikeDbId=23}]
  Starting: LoaderInfo{42281d30 #11 : CursorLoader{42281fe8}}
onLoadComplete: LoaderInfo{42281d30 #11 : CursorLoader{42281fe8}}
  onLoadFinished in CursorLoader{42281fe8 id=11}: CursorWrapperInner{42284950}
onLoadComplete: LoaderInfo{42280538 #12 : CursorLoader{42280580}}
  onLoadFinished in CursorLoader{42280580 id=12}: CursorWrapperInner{42284a48}
restartLoader in LoaderManager{42280020 in RepairInfo{4226cf08}}: args=Bundle[{PartTypeDbId=1, BikeDbId=23}]
  Making last loader inactive: LoaderInfo{42281d30 #11 : CursorLoader{42281fe8}}
  Starting: LoaderInfo{4229d218 #11 : CursorLoader{4229d410}}
onLoadComplete: LoaderInfo{4229d218 #11 : CursorLoader{4229d410}}
  onLoadFinished in CursorLoader{4229d410 id=11}: CursorWrapperInner{4229ecc0}
  Destroying: LoaderInfo{42281d30 #11 : CursorLoader{42281fe8}}
```

Comment: yes you should be consistent, if you are using elements from the support library chances are you should be using everything support library related.

Comment: @tyczj is this defined somewhere in the documentation or your experience with the support library in similar cases?

Comment: you will get build errors if you try to mix things and or unexpected problems that normally wouldnt happen

Comment: After moving  getLoaderManager().initLoader() from onResume() to onCreate() the activity works like expected. I tested this with a Drawer and therefore with the use of the support library only in this part of the app and also with a test version without drawer and without any use of the support library. But the two questions _Does using any part of the support library always enforce using the LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks also from the support library? If yes, where do I find this information?_ are still without a general reply